# No executable found matching command dotnet-projectmodel-server

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I'm getting this error when opening .NET Core projetcs in VS 2015 Community:

> The following error ocurred attempting to run the project model server
>   process (1.0.0-preview-003585).
>
> Unable to start the process. No executable found matching command
>   "dotnet-projectmodel-server".

It was working well until yesterday. I've already tried do reinstall the .NET Core SDK and repair the VS installation.

Some tips?

Comment: Are you running Update 3 of visual studio 2015?

Comment: @MuqeetKhan, yes I am.

Comment: I got this error after I installed latest dev version of CLI `dotnet-dev-win-x64.latest.exe`. No solution yet.

Comment: I'm getting this error now. It started after I installed the RC version of Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I had this same problem.  I was able to fix it by uninstalling **Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 - SDK Preview 3 (x64)** and reinstalling the .NET Core 1.1 SDK from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! Help me as well.

Comment: Awesome, exactly my case!

Comment: Shown in an answer below by @syned, check for all previous versions and delete them too.

Comment: But if you do this, how can you create a new core project in VS015?

Comment: Here's a link to the [Preview2.0.3 exe](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827546&usg=AFQjCNEr5UlkI9ZhPiMRpUjfgcP5Zc2B6w) if anyone else was having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 32):

Another option to fix this is to add a Solution folder called "Solution Items" and add a global.json file in it with an "sdk" element specifying the correct SDK version if you have multiple installed side-by-side.  I installed 2017 RC and I started getting this error because it installs Preview 4.  I don't want to uninstall Preview 4 or 2017 will stop working.  Adding the global.json file with the following text fixed it for me.  (check your %PROGRAMFILES%\dotnet\sdk folder for installed SDK versions.)

```
{ "sdk" : { "version" : "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177" } }
```

Comment: this worked for me with the same situation - not sure I trust VS2017 to convert anything just yet.

Comment: This worked for me also. This is the most elegant and efficient answer for this issue

Answer (score 13):

## Update (11 May, 2017)

According to the new [Announcing .NET Core Tools 1.0 blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/07/announcing-net-core-tools-1-0/):

> We’re now encouraging everyone to migrate to MSBuild and csproj from
>   project.json. As I stated above, we will not be supporting any of the
>   new .NET Core tools in Visual Studio 2015. We also won’t be updating
>   the Visual Studio 2015 project.json-based tools.

## Original answer

There is a closed issue related to this problem in the .NET Core CLI repo:

[Unable to start process "dotnet-projectmodel-server" while starting VS2015](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4621)

According to the post [Changes to Project.json](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/), since *Preview 3* the .NET Core tooling moved from *.xproj/project.json* to *.csproj/MSBuild*. So basically you have three choices:

1. Continue using the *.xproj/project.json* format with a *Preview 2 SDK* (as said in [@Tim Schmidt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683624/2160765))
2. Use the `dotnet migrate` tool or the VS 2017 RC to [migrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/migration/) your existing *project.json* assets to *csproj*. Note that if you are using VS 2015, you will lost the .NET Core Tooling until the *VS 2015 Tools (Preview 2)* is updated.
3. Work with *project.json* and *csproj* on the same machine, switching between the *Preview 2* and *Preview 3+* with the help of the *global.json* file (as said in [@randcd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41640270/2160765)).

But, if you plan to migrate to *.csproj/MSBuild*, pay attention to the post [Using MSBuild to build .NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/target-dotnetcore-with-msbuild):

> We recommend that most people targeting .NET Core with new projects today use the default tooling experience with project.json because of the following reasons:
>
> - MSBuild doesn't yet support a lot of the benefits of project.json
> - A lot of the ASP.NET based tooling doesn't currently work with MSBuild projects
> - When we do release the .NET Core tooling that uses MSBuild, it will be able to automatically convert from project.json to MSBuild projects

Answer (score 7):

I got this message when I was trying out a new Angular2 with .NET Core template from the  ASP.NET Core Template Pack.

Basically, you'll need a global.json file as a Solution Item in the Solution folder (NOT Projects)

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

For more information, you can read further on this page.

[Dot Net Core Tutorials](http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/02/26/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-projectmodel-server/)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, after installing .net core 1.1.0 there were still versions 1.0.1 installed. Delete old versions and reinstall Microsoft .NET Core tools.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error after installing .Net Core 1.0.1 (x64) on Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise following these steps:

1. Installed .Net Core SDK 1.0.1
2. Opened Visual Studio, Went to Tools, Extensions and Updates and saw there was an update for Asp.Net and Web Tools which I chose to to install

I tried to fix it by uninstalling and re-installing the latest version of .Net Core SDK but that didn't solve my problem. I kept getting the error:

[image: fig 1. error dialog]

In my case, I was trying to create a new project using a custom template, so I changed and tried to create a new Asp.Net Core Web Application (.Net Framework) and I got an error that told me exactly what version of the .Net Core SDK I needed:

[image: fig. 2. Dialog indicating the version of SDK]

I followed the link from the dialog (click [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues-vs2015.md#missing-sdk) or go here: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues-vs2015.md#missing-sdk) and downloaded the specific version. I Uninstalled the current .Net Core SDK (1.0.1 x64), then installed the suggested one (1.0.0-preview2-003131 in my case) and that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I has that problem after installing visual studio 2017, I just created a global.json file
with this configuration:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-xxxxx"
  }
}
```

To know which version you are possibly using, open your console and go to **C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk>** then execute a simple dir command, that will list the folders of the different dot net core versions you may have on your system, try one by one and select the version that works for you.

BTW: it worked for me to place the global.json in the project root, not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue after updating [Microsoft Azure SDK v2.9.6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54289)

I uninstalled the 2.9.6 SDK and noticed I had a problem opening my global.json file. So I got the most recent version from VSTS for my solution and that fixed my problem.

Answer (score -2):

Not a good position at all. Dot Net Core 1.0 is the LTS version and this is the one to target. .NET Core 1.1 is NOT the LTS version (and will not run on Amazon for example). So recommending this route goes against Microsoft's policy on LTS versions.

An LTS version MUST continue to be "supported for three years after the general availability date of a LTS release"

Comment: Although I do think that sometimes the best answer to a question is the part of the question unasked... I don't think this is that case. 1.0 vs 1.1 being LTS has nothing to do with the question: `Why am I getting this error?`.