# The F5 isn't working for VS2015 ASP.NET projects in Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've installed recently announced Visual Studio 2017 RC and found out, that in old (VS2015) ASP.NET projects the `Debug->Run` (F5) isn't working: [image: The Start (F5) menu is not working in old ASP.NET projects in Visual Studio 2017]
But from project's contextual menu it is starting as expected: [image: The ASP.NET project contextual menu]

If I `File->New->Project->ASP.NET Web Application` then all is working as always.

Any thoughts on what causing this behaviour?

EDIT: Tried Visual Studio Community 2017 RC - the same behaviour.

Comment: Have you tried setting the startup project and see if that enables the F5 feature?

Comment: Yes, the startup project is the ASP.NET project. I've tried to set another project as startup and than back to proper one - the same.

Comment: Is your project set as start up project from your solution a runnable one ? Maybe the migration of visual studio version has reset your solution settings and set a class library as default startup project

Comment: No. The ASP.NET Web Application project is set as a startup project. And I can run it using `Debug->Start new instance` in context menu.

Comment: Is this the same as issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674393/visual-studio-2017-rc-install-breaks-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-core-projects ?

Comment: @VanKichline, no it's not the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 RC has updated the .csproj file of my web project with this:

```
<servers defaultServer="SelfHostServer">
    <server name="SelfHostServer" exePath="" cmdArgs="" url="http://localhost:51775/" workingDir="" />
</servers>
```

I don't know why this happened, but deleting that solved my problem.