# Error MSB4025: Visual Studio 2015 Package Restore for .NET Core Projects Breaks

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, nuget, .net-core

I was using VS Studio 2015 Professional Edition on Windows 10 Professional for developing .NET Core applications.

Everything was working fine before installing VS 2017 Edition and restarting the OS.

[image]

Now, any project I create it seems that dependencies cannot be installed:

[image]

**project.json:**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

**global.json:**

```
    {
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

**The SDKs installed:**

[image]

Right Click the Project -> **Restore Packages** shows the following:

```
 PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore "c:\Projects\SampleApp\.vs\restore.dg" -s "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages"
c:\Projects\SampleApp\.vs\restore.dg(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

However, if I go to the use the "`dotnet restore`" command at the project directory, it seems it restore the dependencies and works fine.

I have checked some workarounds [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/Documentation/ProjectJsonToCSProj.md), but not working.

Comment: Appears to be a bug in tooling which MSFT says they won't be fixing, see https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5658.

Comment: Thanks, but why that would work on one machine and not on the other, we have the same OS, VS and Preview2 installed. Also, how possible that i installed 2017 but I couldn't find preview3 installed as sdk.

Comment: What`s the result after change the sdk version "1.0.0-preview2-003131" to "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177" in the global.json? or delate the sdk "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177" from the programs list?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT, "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177" preview was there before installing VS 2017, also installing 2017 didn't install any new sdks in that folder. I also tried what you have suggested, its  the same issue in both cases.

Comment: What is the version of your Visual Studio 2017? Have you try to update your Visual Studio 2017 to the RTM?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT, I have included the version in the question, however I cannot find any option in IDE to update or install new updates. I was thinking if uninstalling the VS 2017 would resolve the problem?

Comment: @Hussein Salman, Sorry for the delayed reply. I have ghost a Win 10 VM, install the Visual Studio 2015 and DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe, create a .NET Core project without any error,  then install the Visual Studio 2017 Professional and create a .NET Core project without any error. So this issue should not be related to the installation of VS2017. Have you try to delete the sdk "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177" or reinstall DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe?

Comment: Nothing worked for me so I migrated my projects to VS 2017. Thanks anyway