# Error Loading Project on Vs 2015 update 3 + NETCore.App 1.1.0 Project.json + after vs2017 installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have to load an Asp.net Core Project on [VS2015 update 3]
-The project was made in Visual Studio 2015 update 3

project.json 
       "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.1.0"
    }, ....

After the Visual Studio 2017 installation I'm getting this error
[image]

What's wrong on this configuration ?
How do I solve this issue ?

I tried :
-turning off firewall
-when I Run dotnet run >>

( error msb4019 ) "The imported project c:\program files\Microsoft visual studio\v14.0\dotnet\Microsoft.donet.props was not found. confirm that path in the import declaration is correct...."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017 install breaks Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET Core Projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674393/visual-studio-2017-install-breaks-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-core-projects)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved the error by uninstalling the SDK I had installed (in my case 1.0.4) and installing the latest SDK that works with VS 2015 which is 1.0.0-preview2-003131. You can find the Visual Studio 2015 tools on their [downloads page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core).

A global.json that works for VS 2015 looks like this:

`{
  "projects": [],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}`