# Unable to open vs2015 .net core 1.1 project after installing vs2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015

I was working in vs2015 with .net core 1.1 a few months back.  I upgraded to vs2017.  I had some problems getting vs2017 to work while vs2015 was installed, I finally got it to work by uninstalling vs2015 and vs2017 and just installing vs2017.

Today I was tasked with working on a vs2015 project which they do not wish to upgrade to vs2017 at this time.

First obstacle was just organization - you see the TFS structure is like this:

```
-Root
+ Project A ( vs2015 )
+ Project B ( vs2015 )
+ Project C ( vs2017 )
+ Project D ( vs2015 )
```

VS and TFS will not allow me to change the local directory form c:\Root\Project C to c:\Root\VS2015\Project B -- oh well.

I reinstalled VS2015 with service pack 3.  Fired it up and downloaded a vs2015 project from TFS.  The problem comes when I try to open it.  When I open the Solution from Source Control Explorer I get this error:

[image]

Clicking OK opens the Migration report in my browser:

[image]

Clicking on any of the links ([Migration Report Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674393/visual-studio-2017-install-breaks-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-core-projects)) goes to a page about ".NET Core installation guide".
I navigated to the vs2015 version and re-downloaded the .net installation exe, but when I ran it I only had an option to repair, which I did but didn't help.

My solution remains in this broken state, unable to open the projects in the solution:
[image]

Right clicking on any of the projects and trying to reopen the project brings up the migration report error again.

I did find a similar reported issue at [Visual Studio 2017 install breaks Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET Core Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674393/visual-studio-2017-install-breaks-visual-studio-2015-asp-net-core-projects)

but my solution did contain a gloabl.json file in the root and changing the contents of the file from:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
  }
}
```

to:

```
{
  "projects": [],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

Didn't help.  I also ran a dotnet --version and got the result 1.03 and used that in the version string, but still no joy.

Any ideas on how to open these vs205 .net core projects?   I also read that others who have had this issue that uninstalling vs2015 and vs2017 and just reinstalling vs2015 does not help either.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. .NET Core support for VS2015 is always a preview, so don't expect it to work all the time. Tell your team what happened and urge them to migrate to VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be an incompatible .net core installation.  I had the newest .net core installed but the project will only open with

```
"DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe".
```