# No executable found matching command dotnet-projectmodel-server, VS2015

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to build a new front end application with dotnet core but getting an error as below while to open the project.

i followed that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391132/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-projectmodel-server) but not working for me.

[image: here is the error i am getting]

[image: dotnet --info]

[image: project]

getting this error while trying to restore :

error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

running dotnet restore command gives below error :

error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.1\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Comment: Have you followed https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/Documentation/ProjectJsonToCSProj.md#how-do-i-work-with-projectjson-and-csproj-on-the-same-machine and updated your global.json to include a specific SDK version?

Comment: you mean adding a global.json file to solution

Comment: Normally you should have `global.json` in your solution when you create a new project. Can you post a screenshot of your solution files tree?

Comment: just added global.json file it was not there

Comment: updated question with image

Comment: And after you add content to `global.json` as in https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/Documentation/ProjectJsonToCSProj.md#how-do-i-work-with-projectjson-and-csproj-on-the-same-machine and restart Visual Studio, does it work?

Comment: same error comes on restart

Comment: Any chance you could upload minimal solution somewhere so I could try on my machine?

Comment: Sure i will upload it to google drive and share a link with you

Comment: @Ignas I am able to resolve the issue. Actually preview 2 SDK was not installed properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem yesterday.
Unfortunately, I don't know exactly what I was doing wrong, but I managed to solve my error.

I used the strategy on this page [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/Documentation/ProjectJsonToCSProj.md#how-do-i-work-with-projectjson-and-csproj-on-the-same-machine)

I added a global.json file in my Solution Items and I specified all the .xproj projects of my solution.

```
{
    "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Running dotnet-restore solved this issue for me. This was after i had updated the global.js to tarket the specific SDK version.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-restore