# Unable to start the process.No executable found matching command "dotnet-projectmodel-server"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, sdk

Kindly click on below links to show the image.

I have re-install the .Net Core SDK 1.0.1 (x64) multiple times along with the Microsoft .Net Version Manager (x64) 1.0.0-rc1 ,Microsoft .Net Core 1.0.1-VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 but getting the same error and if you notice in solution explorer there is no global.json file.

[image]

After click on ok and rebuild so getting new error
[image]

Comment: Kindly click on the blue links to show the image

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391132/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-projectmodel-server
(Jelgam answer).

Comment: i am also getting the same error and could not find a solution